# Replicating Stata's "robust" option in R

Tags: r, stata, robust, robust-standard-error

I have been trying to replicate the results of the Stata option `robust` in R. I have used the `rlm` command form the MASS package and also the command `lmrob` from the package "robustbase". In both cases the results are quite different from the "robust" option in Stata. Can anybody please suggest something in this context?

Here are the results I obtained when I ran the robust option in Stata:

```
. reg yb7 buildsqb7 no_bed no_bath rain_harv swim_pl pr_terrace, robust

Linear regression                                      Number of obs =    4451
                                                       F(  6,  4444) =  101.12
                                                       Prob > F      =  0.0000
                                                       R-squared     =  0.3682
                                                       Root MSE      =   .5721

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         yb7 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   buildsqb7 |   .0046285   .0026486     1.75   0.081    -.0005639     .009821
      no_bed |   .3633841   .0684804     5.31   0.000     .2291284    .4976398
     no_bath |   .0832654   .0706737     1.18   0.239    -.0552904    .2218211
   rain_harv |   .3337906   .0395113     8.45   0.000     .2563289    .4112524
     swim_pl |   .1627587   .0601765     2.70   0.007     .0447829    .2807346
  pr_terrace |   .0032754   .0178881     0.18   0.855    -.0317941    .0383449
       _cons |   13.68136   .0827174   165.40   0.000     13.51919    13.84353
```

And this is what I obtained in R with the lmrob option:

```
> modelb7<-lmrob(yb7~Buildsqb7+No_Bed+Rain_Harv+Swim_Pl+Gym+Pr_Terrace, data<-bang7)
> summary(modelb7)

Call:
lmrob(formula = yb7 ~ Buildsqb7 + No_Bed + Rain_Harv + Swim_Pl + Gym + Pr_Terrace, 
    data = data <- bang7)
 \--> method = "MM"
Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-51.03802  -0.12240   0.02088   0.18199   8.96699 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 12.648261   0.055078 229.641   <2e-16 ***
Buildsqb7    0.060857   0.002050  29.693   <2e-16 ***
No_Bed       0.005629   0.019797   0.284   0.7762    
Rain_Harv    0.230816   0.018290  12.620   <2e-16 ***
Swim_Pl      0.065199   0.028121   2.319   0.0205 *  
Gym          0.023024   0.014655   1.571   0.1162    
Pr_Terrace   0.015045   0.013951   1.078   0.2809    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Robust residual standard error: 0.1678 
Multiple R-squared:  0.8062,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8059
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I made your title a little bit more descriptive and added some formatting. In general, programming questions aren't on topic here, **but** I think yours is because it involves some statistical issues. Hope to see you around....

Comment: It would help tremendously if you at least pasted the code used to estimate the models in Stata and R (even better if you provide an entirely reproducible example). When you say "results differ" - if you are estimating the same model only the standard errors should differ, not the coefficient estimates.

Comment: okay... These are the results I obtained by the robust option in STATA:

Comment: looks like `lmrob` is not the same as `reg y x, robust`.  Google "heteroskedasticity-consistent standard errors R".  You'll get pages showing you how to use the `lmtest` and `sandwich` libraries.

Comment: Yes, I know they are not the same. I am asking if anybody can provide a command in R that replicates the robust option in Stata. I tried the sandwich package but unfortunately that too is not exactly the same as the robust option in Stata.

Comment: Stata uses a small sample correction factor of n/(n-k). R usually does something else, so make sure you adjust for that.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov you are right. In order to get that same small-sample adjustment that Stata does with R's coeftest and sandwich libraries, use `coeftest(model, vcov.=vcovHC(model,type="HC1"))`, where `model=lm(y~x)`. You can see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich.pdf) how the options differ. I think "HC3" is used if you do not specify any option and just use `coeftest(model, vcov.=vcovHC)`.

Answer (score 61):

Charles is nearly there in his answer, but `robust` option of the `regress` command (and other regression estimation commands) in Stata makes it possible to use multiple types of heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation robust variance-covariance matrix estimators, as does the `coeftest` function in the [`lmtest`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmtest/index.html) package, which in turn depends on the respective variance-covariance matrices produced by the `vcovHC` function in the [`sandwich`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich) package.

However, the default variance-covariance matrices used by the two is different:
1. The default variance-covariance matrix returned by `vcocHC` is the so-called `HC3` for reasons described in the man page for `vcovHC`.
2. The `sandwich` option used by Charles makes `coeftest` use the `HC0` robust variance-covariance matrix.
3. To reproduce the Stata default behavior of using the `robust` option in a call to `regress` you need to request `vcovHC` to use the `HC1` robust variance-covariance matrix.

Read more about it [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich.pdf).

The following example that demonstrates all the points made above is based on the example [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter4/statareg4.htm).

```
library(foreign)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

dfAPI = read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/elemapi2.dta")
lmAPI = lm(api00 ~ acs_k3 + acs_46 + full + enroll, data= dfAPI)
summary(lmAPI)                                  # non-robust

# check that "sandwich" returns HC0
coeftest(lmAPI, vcov = sandwich)                # robust; sandwich
coeftest(lmAPI, vcov = vcovHC(lmAPI, "HC0"))    # robust; HC0 

# check that the default robust var-cov matrix is HC3
coeftest(lmAPI, vcov = vcovHC(lmAPI))           # robust; HC3 
coeftest(lmAPI, vcov = vcovHC(lmAPI, "HC3"))    # robust; HC3 (default)

# reproduce the Stata default
coeftest(lmAPI, vcov = vcovHC(lmAPI, "HC1"))    # robust; HC1 (Stata default)
```

The last line of code above reproduces results from Stata:

```
use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/elemapi2
regress api00 acs_k3 acs_46 full enroll, robust
```

Comment: Link to data is dead. Can you please update the link? Is this same file: http://faculty.smu.edu/tfomby/eco5350/data/Examples/elemapi2.dta   ?

Comment: How to reproduce also confidence intervals?

Comment: How can I do it if the model is a GLM?

Answer (score 33):

I found a description on the following website that replicates Stata's ''robust'' option in R.

https://economictheoryblog.com/2016/08/08/robust-standard-errors-in-r

Following the instructions, all you need to do is load a function into your R session and then set the parameter ''robust'' in you summary function to TRUE.

```
summary(lm.object, robust=TRUE)
```

Comment: Masking `summary.lm()`, as happens here, is bound to lead to pain. I do not recommend this approach. Especially since `summary()` is masked with an arbitrary function from a Github repo, which could change at any moment, or even be malicious!

Comment: robust=T outputted the exact same result as if I never included the option

Answer (score 15):

As of April 2018 I believe you want the [`estimatr` package](http://estimatr.declaredesign.org/), which provides a near drop in replacement for `lm`. Several examples pulled nearly from the documentation:

```
library(estimatr)
library(car)

# HC1 robust standard errors
model <- lm_robust(GPA_year2 ~ gpa0 + ssp, data = alo_star_men,
                   se_type = "stata")
summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm_robust(formula = GPA_year2 ~ gpa0 + ssp, data = alo_star_men, 
#>     se_type = "stata")
#> 
#> Standard error type:  HC1 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error  Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper  DF
#> (Intercept) -3.60625    1.60084 0.0258665 -6.77180  -0.4407 137
#> gpa0         0.06814    0.02024 0.0009868  0.02812   0.1082 137
#> ssp          0.31917    0.18202 0.0817589 -0.04077   0.6791 137
#> 
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.09262 ,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.07937 
#> F-statistic: 6.992 on 2 and 137 DF,  p-value: 0.001284

# HC1 cluster robust standard errors
model2 <- lm_robust(GPA_year2 ~ gpa0 + ssp, cluster = ssp,
                   data = alo_star_men, se_type = "stata")
summary(model2)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm_robust(formula = GPA_year2 ~ gpa0 + ssp, data = alo_star_men, 
#>     clusters = ssp, se_type = "stata")
#> 
#> Standard error type:  stata 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper DF
#> (Intercept) -3.60625   1.433195 0.240821 -21.8167  14.6042  1
#> gpa0         0.06814   0.018122 0.165482  -0.1621   0.2984  1
#> ssp          0.31917   0.004768 0.009509   0.2586   0.3798  1
#> 
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.09262 ,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.07937 
#> F-statistic: 6.992 on 2 and 137 DF,  p-value: 0.001284
```

The `car` package then makes it easy to perform omnibus hypothesis tests for these models:

```
linearHypothesis(model, c("gpa0 = ssp"))
#> Linear hypothesis test
#> 
#> Hypothesis:
#> gpa0 - ssp = 0
#> 
#> Model 1: restricted model
#> Model 2: GPA_year2 ~ gpa0 + ssp
#> 
#>   Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
#> 1    138                     
#> 2    137  1 1.8859     0.1697
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd edit the question. You're confusing robust regression with Stata's robust command. There seems to be no benefit to introducing this confusion.

I think there are a few approaches. I haven't looked at them all and not sure which is the best:

#### The sandwich package:

```
library(sandwich)    
coeftest(model, vcov=sandwich)
```

But this doesn't give me the same answers I get from Stata for some reason. I've never tried to work out why - but above in comments there is a suggested answer - I just don't use this package.

#### The rms package:

I find this a bit of a pain to work with but usually get good answers with some effort. And it is the most useful for me.

```
model = ols(a~b, x=TRUE)    
robcov(model)
```

#### You can code it from scratch

See this blog post (http://thetarzan.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/heteroskedasticity-robust-and-clustered-standard-errors-in-r/). It looks like the most painful option, but remarkably easy and this option often works the best.

Comment: Charles is correct on the main point, but to make explicit what is implied elsewhere note that Stata has no `robust` command! (There is a programmer's command `_robust`, not directly relevant here.) Rather, to get robust (Huber-Eicker-White-sandwich) standard errors, the modern approach in Stata is to specify `vce(robust)` as an option. The older approach to specify a `robust` option still works. More broadly, the confusion caused by the difference between robust regression (etc.) and "robust" SEs is unfortunate.

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot. The codes work and it does indeed provide with the results that Stata does. Just a question. I understand that robust regression is different from robust standard errors, and that robust regression is used when your data contains outliers. But it also solves the problem of heteroskedasticity. Could anyone please tell me whether the MM kind estimation provided by the "lmrob" command from package "robustbase" be used as a solution to the problem of outliers and heteroskedasticity simultaneuosly?

Comment: @user56579 My guess is that you want to ask a separate question about this.