# Robust Variance in Stata and R?

Tags: r, stata, robust-standard-error

There are already a lot of good questions on this topic (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117052/replicating-statas-robust-option-in-r)). But they address complexities that I am not interested in.

I have some simple data. I am using basic GLM and OLS, with robust variance estimators. In Stata, I'm inputting:

```
input deadspace asthma
43 0
44 0
45 0
56 0
56 0
57 0
58 0
64 0
31 1
78 1
79 1
88 1
92 1
101 1 
112 1
end
```

And in R, I'm inputting:

```
a1 <- c(43,44,45,56,56,57,58,64)
a2 <- c(31,78,79,88,92,101,112)

deadspace <- c(a1,a2)
asthma <- c(rep(0,length(a1)),rep(1,length(a2)))
```

My objective is to understand how to equate results from Stata and R for simple GLMs. I have succeeded at this task when OLS is used (i.e., regress in Stata, and lm in R). But when I use GLMs, I get different SE estimates, even when I use the same robust variance estimator. For example, in Stata, running:

`glm deadspace asthma, irls family(gaussian) link(identity) vce(robust)`

Gives a robust standard error for the asthma coefficient of 9.74. Based on other findings, it seems that Stata's default robust variance estimator is HC1. So, using this in R with a corresponding GLM:

```
mod1 <- glm(deadspace ~ asthma,family=gaussian(link="identity"))
coeftest(mod1, vcov = vcovHC(mod1, type="HC1"))
```

I get a standard error estimate of 10.11. Trying different HC variations in R does not give me a result that matches the Stata estimate.

However, if I used the "unbiased" option in Stata:

`glm deadspace asthma, irls family(gaussian) link(identity) vce(unbiased)`

I get an SE estimate of 10.16, which matches the corresponding R estimate when the HC2 variance estimator is used:

```
mod1 <- glm(deadspace ~ asthma,family=gaussian(link="identity"))
coeftest(mod1, vcov = vcovHC(mod1, type="HC2"))[2,2]
```

But this is the only way I've been able to equate robust variance estimates with GLM from Stata and R. Why is that?

Based on an article linked [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/sandwich-estimate-of-variance/), it seems Stata implements a small sample adjustment by default. But it is not clear to me which adjustment is being used. How can I modify either:

1. the Stata code to give the same HC1 estimate of 10.11 that R returns when HC1 is used, or
2. the R code to get the SE estimate of 9.74 that Stata returns when `vce(robust)` is used?

Alternatively, I'd settle for the EXACT equation that is being used to compute the value of 9.74 in Stata with `vce(robust)`.

Comment: `coeftest(mod1, vcov = vcovCL)` will give you the same adjustment by default as in Stata, i.e., with $n - 1$ rather than $n$ or $n - k$. See also my comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stata uses a small sample adjustment for their GLM function, in which the standard sandwich variance (obtained via the `vce(robust)` command) is scaled according to the sample size and the number of parameters in the model. R uses no such adjustment. Thus, the specific relation between the sandwich SE from Stata and R (specifying HC1 when using the latter) is:

$$ SE_{sandwich, Stata} = \left (SE_{sandwich, R} \right ) \times \sqrt{ (n-k)/(n-1) } $$

where $n$ is the sample size, and $k$ is the number of parameters in the model. Thus, for the specific problem, the sandwich standard error estimate obtained in R was 10.11. Using the above equation with two parameters (intercept and asthma coefficient) and a sample size of 15, we can convert the R estimate (10.11) to it's corresponding Stata value (9.74) as:

$$ 10.11 \times \sqrt{(15-2)/(15-1)} = 9.74$$

Comment: In fact, the `sandwich` package in R always provided adjustment with either $n - k$ or with $n$. Just the adjustment with $n - 1$ didn't use to be available in previous versions, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367974/different-robust-standard-errors-of-logit-regression-in-stata-and-r/27368468#27368468 However, since we added clustered standard errors $n - 1$ is also easily available via `vcovCL()` by default (i.e., when each observation is its own cluster). See also: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich-CL.pdf