# Why sandwich estimators aren't always used in OLS regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, sandwich

I asked before what is the [intuition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76904/robust-regression-and-sandwich-estimators) behind sandwich estimators. I must still missing something because I don't understand why sandwich estimators are not always applied to OLS residuals.

Can you explain what sandwich estimators do in English and why we don't see them always applied to OLS models?

Comment: In short, they're less *efficient* than the classic SEs, given that the assumptions behind these hold.

Comment: @abaumann Less efficient in what?

Comment: If you know for sure that the underlying model is linear with Gaussian residuals then what the estimator may see as outliers is real data that shouldn't be discarded.

Comment: @RobertKubrick http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_%28statistics%29

Comment: @abaumann So can we say that for large sets (say, more than 5,000 observations) sandwich estimators are always preferable? Why to use the standard diagonal std errors? Then again, unless the residuals are extremely heavy-tailed, the larger the sample the less likely the standard errors bias...